# Plotly texttemplate appears to ignore actual string template

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

From this part of the [documentation](https://import%20plotly.graph_objects%20as%20go), I expected the following code to produce a bar graph, where each bars contain the corresponding text as per `df['label']`. Instead, each bar contains the string found in `df['Foo']`. How can I get the `texttemplate` to work properly, i.e., have each bar contain the text from `df['label']`?

```
>>> import plotly
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import plotly.graph_objects as go

>>> plotly.__version__ 
5.17.0

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Foo":['a','b','c'],'Bar':[2,5,10], 'label':['alpha','beta', 'charlie']})
df
        Foo     Bar     label
    0   a       2       alpha
    1   b       5       beta
    2   c       10      charlie

>>> bar = go.Bar(x=df['Foo'], y=df['Bar'], texttemplate ="%{label}")
>>> go.Figure(data=bar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change **texttemplate** by **text** like this:

```
bar = go.Bar(x=df['Foo'], y=df['Bar'], text =df['label'])
```

Comment: Or also you can change **"%{label}"** by **df["label"]**

Comment: But this won't allow me to use the actual functionality of texttemplate, which is what I want.

Comment: Have you tried this `bar = go.Bar(x=df['Foo'], y=df['Bar'],texttemplate = df['label'])`

Answer (score 0):

The first answer was quite close. You have to put your label names in the `text=` attribute and use it in `texttemplate=`

```
bar = go.Bar(x=df['Foo'], y=df['Bar'],
             text = df['label'],
             texttemplate = "labeltext: %{label}<br>my text: %{text}",)
```

[image]